# White spot on cactus? Can someone help identify and find a fix?

Tags: succulents, cactus

[image]

I’ve had this problem for a little while, maybe a month? I haven’t noticed any spraying but I am worried about his health over all. He’s indoor and was in natural light when this began and is now under a plant light.